# Compilation fails when using a lambda for Supplier<? extends Type>

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, option-type

Why does this not compile? :

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Demo {

    Optional<? extends SomeValue> getOption() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    void exposure() {
        SomeValue someValue = getOption().orElseGet(() -> new SomeValue());
    }
}

class SomeValue {}
```

It works without problem when `getOption()` would return a `Optional<SomeValue>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of a rather restricted method signature:

```
public T orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other) {
```

In your case, `T` is `? extends SomeValue` which is an unknown type being assignable to `SomeValue` (but may be a subclass of it). The signature of `orElseGet` implies that your supplier is allowed to return a subtype of `T`, having the overall result type of `T` but it does not allow to do a widening to a common base type of `T` and the type your supplier returns (If your supplier returns `SomeValue` and `T` is `? extends SomeValue`, the common base type would be `SomeValue`).

You can fix this by inserting an operation which allows widening of the type:

```
SomeValue someValue = getOption()
  .map(Function.<SomeValue>identity()).orElseGet(() -> new SomeValue());
```

The `identity` function does not change the value, but the mapping operation allows to pass in a function consuming a broader type, i.e. the mapping function may declare to consume `SomeValue` when the actual input type is `? extends SomeValue` and the return type is `SomeValue`.

---

But generally, to avoid such problems, methods should not have wildcards in their return types, so change

```
Optional<? extends SomeValue> getOption()
```

to

```
Optional<SomeValue> getOption()
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html

> Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

`Optional<T>.orElseGet` is specified to accept a `Supplier<? extends T>`.  But the meaning of `Optional<? extends SomeValue>` is that it could be an `Optional<MySubClassOfSomeValue>`, in which case a `Supplier<SomeValue>` would not be a `Supplier<? extends MySubClassOfSomeValue>`.

`orElseGet` must return a subtype of the element type of the `Optional`, and `? extends SomeValue` may be something other than `SomeValue`.

Comment: So basically, it is a supplier that cannot be implemented, as it is not possible to supply an instance that is an instance of every possible subclass of `SomeValue` ?

Comment: Correct.  `orElseGet` is pretty much useless _if_ your `Optional` is a `? extends`.  (Though you could possibly return null or throw an exception of your choice.)